# How to restrict image size to a specific size when uploading in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

My controller function is

```
public function add() { 
    $blog_title  = $this->input->post("qes_blog_title"); 
    $description = htmlentities($_POST['qes_blog_description']); 
    $edit_status = $this->input->post("edit"); 
    $filename    = $blog_title . date('ymdhis'); 
    if ($this->session->userdata('user_type') == "SA") { 
        $dirname  = (dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))) . 
            '/uploads/blog/admin'; 
        $usertype = "1"; 
    } else { 
        $dirname  = (dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))) . '/uploads/blog/' 
            . $this->session->userdata('user_id'); 
        $usertype = "0"; 
    } 
    if (!file_exists($dirname)) { 
        mkdir($dirname, 0777, true); 
    } 
    $config['upload_path']   = $dirname; 
    $config['file_name']     = $filename; 
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|jpg|png'; 
    $this->load->library('upload', $config); 
    $this->upload->initialize($config); 
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload("qes_blog_image")) { 
        //print_r($this->upload->display_errors()); 
        $data = array( 
            'qes_blog_title' => $blog_title, 
            'qes_blog_description' => $description, 
            'qes_vendor_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'), 
            'qes_user_type' => $usertype, 
            'qes_created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s') 
        ); 
    } else { 
        if ($edit_status) { 
            $condition       = array( 
                'qes_vendor_blog_id' => $edit_status 
            ); 
            $categoryDetails = $this->common_model->get_row($condition, $this->tablename); 
            if ($categoryDetails->qes_category_image != NULL) { 
                if ($this->session->userdata('user_type') == "SA") { 
                    unlink((dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))) . '/uploads/blog/admin/' . $categoryDetails->qes_blog_image); 
                } else { 
                    unlink((dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))) . '/uploads/blog/' . $categoryDetails->qes_vendor_id . "/" . $categoryDetails->qes_blog_image); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        $uploqes_data     = $this->upload->data(); 
        $uploqes_filename = $uploqes_data['file_name']; 
        $data             = array( 
            'qes_blog_title' => $blog_title, 
            'qes_blog_description' => $description, 
            'qes_vendor_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'), 
            'qes_user_type' => $usertype, 
            'qes_blog_image' => $uploqes_filename, 
            'qes_created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s') 
        ); 
    } 
    $condition    = array( 
        'qes_blog_title' => $blog_title 
    ); 
    $blog_details = $this->common_model->get_row($condition, $this->tablename); 
    if ($edit_status) { 
        if (count($blog_details) > 0) { 
            if ($blog_details->qes_blog_title == $blog_title) { 
                $condition = array( 
                    'qes_vendor_blog_id' => $edit_status 
                ); 
                $result    = $this->common_model->update_row($data, $condition, $this->tablename); 
                $status    = 'Blog "<b>' . $blog_title . '</b>" Successfully Updated'; 
            } else { 
                $htm    = "0"; 
                $result = "0"; 
                $status = "0"; 
            } 
        } else { 
            $condition = array( 
                'qes_vendor_blog_id' => $edit_status 
            ); 
            $result    = $this->common_model->update_row($data, $condition, $this->tablename); 
            $status    = 'Blog "<b>' . $blog_title . '</b>" Successfully Updated'; 
        } 
    } else { 
        if (count($blog_details) > 0) { 
            if ($blog_details->qes_blog_title == $blog_title) { 
                $htm    = "0"; 
                $result = "0"; 
                $status = "0"; 
            } else { 
                $result = $this->common_model->insert_data($this->tablename, $data); 
                $status = 'Blog "<b>' . $blog_title . '</b>" Successfully Created'; 
            } 
        } else { 
            $result = $this->common_model->insert_data($this->tablename, $data); 
            $status = 'Blog "<b>' . $blog_title . '</b>" Successfully Created'; 
        } 
    } 
    if ($result) { 
        $htm = $result; 
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', $status); 
    } else { 
        $htm = '0'; 
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'Error While Creating Parent'); 
    } 
    echo $htm; 
}
```

I'm a beginner in Codeigniter.

How to restrict the size of image while uploading. Only images of specific size can be uploaded. The above is the controller function to add blog. How to specify the size in the above code. How to keep a condition like "upload image only of the specified size" while uploading image in Codeigniter?

Comment: Do you mean file size or image size?

Comment: i meant the image size

Comment: Please check my updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47588467/1393400). This should solve your problem.

Comment: Is image (file) mandatory to be uploaded or just optional?

Comment: image is mandatory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer this code, this may help you..thanks!

```
    $file_name = '';
            $error = '';
            if ($_FILES['image']['name'] != '') {

                $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/blog/main/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg';
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
                    $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
                } else {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                    $file_name = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
                    $config['source_image'] = 'uploads/blog/main/' . $file_name;
                    $config['new_image'] = 'uploads/blog/thumb/' . $file_name;

                    $config['width'] = 172;
                    $config['height'] = 122;
                    $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
                    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
                    $this->image_lib->resize();
                    $this->image_lib->clear();
                    if ($data['upload_data']['image_height'] > $this->main_height || $data['upload_data']['image_width'] > $this->main_width) {
                        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                        $config['source_image'] = 'uploads/blog/main/' . $file_name;
                        $config['new_image'] = 'uploads/blog/main/' . $file_name;
                        $config['width'] = $this->main_width;
                        $config['height'] = $this->main_height;
                        $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
                        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
                        $this->image_lib->resize();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

If you want to restrict the image size to a specific `width` and `height`, set both **minimum** and **maximum** of `width` and `height` to the same value in the config. For eg. to restrict image size to 1024x768, you can set the preferences in config as follows

```
$config['min_width']       = '1024';         // restrict width to 1024px
$config['min_height']      = '768';          // restrict height to 768px
$config['max_width']       = '1024';         // restrict width to 1024px
$config['max_height']      = '768';          // restrict height to 768px

$this->load->library('upload', $config);     // pass the config when loading the library
```

If you use `autoload`, pass the **config** to the `initialize` method.

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

*Side note:*
I see that you are passing the `config` while loading the library and then also initializing. This is redundant. `initialize` method is used if you are using the `autoload` feature.

Answer (score 0):

instead of copy pasting the raw code , let me give you the sample for each actions you like to do with image uploading in php. so that you can make us of any of below to achieve your result.

**1. To check if image is received or not. use,**

```
if(isset($_FILES["image"])){
// image received
} else {
// image not received
}
```

**2. To check if the image is properly uploaded or not. use,**

```
if ($_FILES['image']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
// error
   die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['image']['error']);
} else {
// no error
}
```

**3. To check if your image is in valid format. use,**

```
$info = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
if ($info === FALSE) {

//Unable to determine image type of uploaded file

}

if (($info[2] !== IMAGETYPE_GIF) && ($info[2] !== IMAGETYPE_JPEG) && ($info[2] !== IMAGETYPE_PNG)) {

// File received is not in valid format

}
```

**4. to get size of the image, use above method and as well as,**

```
$width = $info[0];
$height = $info[1];
```

**4.1 To check if image is square,**

```
if($width!=$height) {
//Image is not square
}
```

**4.1 To check minimum pixel image width**

```
if($width<50) { // Image width should be atleast 50 pixel }
```

*you can play with conditional statement to receive the required image size you are looking for.*

5. **To upload the image ( not exactly need to be in below format, modify it according to the need ),**

   $imagename=($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);

   $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];

   $temp = explode(".",$_FILES["image"]["name"]);

   $filename = rand(1,99999).'.'.end($temp);

   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "../your_path/" . $filename);

Comment: if you can understand this , then you can easily convert it in to codeigniter